# Saving Pandas DataFrame and meta-data to JSON format

Tags: json, pandas, python-2.7

I have a need to save a Pandas DataFrame, along with some metadata to a file in JSON format.  (The JSON format is a requirement.)

**Background**
**A)** I can successfully read/write my rather large Pandas Dataframe from/to JSON using `DataFrame.to_json()` and `DataFrame.from_json()`.  No problems.

**B)** I have no problems saving my metadata (dict) to JSON using `json.dump()`/`json.load()`

**My first attempt**
Since Pandas does not support DataFrame metadata directly, my first thought was to

```
top_level_dict = {}
top_level_dict['data'] = df.to_dict()
top_level_dict['metadata'] = {'some':'stuff'}
json.dump(top_level_dict, fp)
```

**Failure modes**
**C)**   I have found that even the simplified case of

```
df_dict = df.to_dict()
json.dump(df_dict, fp)
```

fails with:

```
TypeError: key (u'US', 112, 5, 80, 'wl') is not a string
```

**D)** Investigating, I've found that the complement also fails.

```
df.to_json(fp)
json.load(fp)
```

fails with

```
384             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 1 column 17 (char 16)
```

So it appears that Pandas JSON format and the Python's JSON library are not compatible.

My first thought is to chase down a way to modify the `df.to_dict()` output of **C** to make it amenable to Python's JSON library, but I keep hearing "If you're struggling to do something in Python, you're probably doing it wrong." in my head.

**Question**
What is the cannonical/recommended method for adding metadata to a Pandas DataFrame and storing to a JSON-formatted file?

Python 2.7.10
Pandas 0.17

**Edit 1:**
While trying out Evan Wright's great answer, I found the source of my problems: Pandas (as of 0.17) does not like saving Multi-Indexed DataFrames to JSON.  The library I had created to save my (Multi-Indexed) DataFrames is quietly performing a `df.reset_index()` before calling `DataFrame.to_json()`.  My newer code was not.  So it was `DataFrame.to_json()` burping on the MultiIndex.

Lesson: Read the documentation kids, even when it's *your own* documentation.

**Edit 2:**

If you need to store both the DataFrame and the metadata in a *single* JSON object, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to just put the data on separate lines.

Writing:

```
f = open('test.json', 'w')
df.to_json(f)
print >> f
json.dump(metadata, f)
```

Reading:

```
f = open('test.json')
df = pd.read_json(next(f))
metdata = json.loads(next(f))
```

Comment: Writing as two separate strings in the file. Nice technique.

Answer (score 3):

In my question, I erroneously stated that I needed the JSON in a file.  In that situation, Evan Wright's answer is my preferred solution.

In my case, I actually need to store the JSON output as a single "blob" in a database, so my dictionary-wrangling approach appears to be necessary.

If you similarly need to store the data and metadata in a single JSON blob, the following code will work:

```
top_level_dict = {}
top_level_dict['data'] = df.to_dict()
top_level_dict['metadata'] = {'some':'stuff'}
with open(FILENAME, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(top_level_dict, outfile)
```

Just make sure DataFrame is singly-indexed.  If it's Multi-Indexed, reset the index (i.e. `df.reset_index()`) before doing the above.

Reading the data back in:

```
with open(FILENAME, 'r') as infile:
    top_level_dict = json.load(infile)

df_as_dict = top_level_dict.pop('data', {})
df = pandas.DataFrame().as_dict(df_as_dict)

meta = top_level_dict['metadata']
```

At this point, you'll need to re-create your Multi-Index (if applicable)

Comment: This answer is great! Regarding reading data back in, it looks that _pandas_ API has changed and currently `from_dict` should be used instead of `as_dict`.